# How to make a call to secured web service(HTTPS) using basic http binding?

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services

I need to import some model file into a Sharepoint central admin(HTTPS) from my local machine. What should be the configuration(using service.model)?
I am using the following configuration...

      
        
            
             
              
            
        
      

 
      
        binding="basicHttpBinding"
        bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_BusinessDataCatalogSharedService"
        contract="BusinessDataCatalogSharedService"              name="BasicHttpBinding_BusinessDataCatalogSharedService" />

And i am using the following c# code...
BusinessDataCatalogSharedServiceClient client = 
                new BusinessDataCatalogSharedServiceClient("BasicHttpBinding_BusinessDataCatalogSharedService1");
 client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "...";
            client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "....";

I am getting the following error

MessageSecurityException was unhandeled
The HTTP request was forbidden with client authentication scheme 'Basic'.

I dont have enough knowledge about the authentication...Please help me out.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this information http://blog.adnanmasood.com/2008/07/16/https-with-basichttpbinding-note-to-self/

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the problem is that you are running the service over HTTP not HTTPS. This will not work with username/password authentication. WCF is secure by default such that it will disallow calls with this type of authentication over HTTP.

You need to configure your service with a certificate to run over HTTPS and then also make the appropriate changes to you config (as is described in the link renu has posted).